# TypeScript 'string' returned from function

Tags: typescript

I have a function `translateNumericDayToString` that returns a string with the name of the day (for example "monday"):

```
export function translateNumericDayToString(day: number) {
  const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
  return days[day];
}
```

I have a json type and the following code:

```
type days = {
  sunday: {
    ...
  },
  monday: {
    ...
  },
}

currentDayIndex = 1
const currentDay: keyof typeof days = translateNumericDayToString(currentDayIndex);
```

I'm getting `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"monday" | "tuesday" | "wednesday" | "thursday" | "friday" | "saturday" | "sunday"''`

When I change to `const currentDay: keyof typeof days = "monday"` it works as expected.

Why? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) ("const assertions", introduced in Typescript 3.4). As it is, Typescript sees an array of strings and assumes that the array is mutable. With `as const`, Typescript correctly understands that the array is a list of constant values.

```js
export function translateNumericDayToString(day: number) {
  const days = ['sunday', /*...*/ 'saturday'] as const;
                                           // ^^^^^^^^
  return days[day];
}

// return type is now "sunday" | /* ... */ | "saturday"
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVxlAQxQGcAbAmYAOSQFtgpM0ARAgTwBUIBlfTFAOYAKACbsAXHBR0ARgwCUcAN4AoOHDQ5i8MW2JwAvHADaAcmKpdpgDRxTtHFdumYSYMSd2A7sBEp3ni4AFkhQHuw2dgiMgcQUoVYAunAE+pokMADcanBQwK5QuLrExrqJ2QC+QA)

Comment: In Deno this works: `const currentDayIndex = 1;
const currentDay: string = translateNumericDayToString(currentDayIndex);
console.log(currentDay);`.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation.